# Reducing py2exe distribution size, while including some numpy functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, py2exe, software-distribution

I have a program which is currently dependent on `numpy` which I have been working on converting with `py2exe`. My issue is that even with a script such as

```
from numpy import array
print array(1)
```

that only uses the function `numpy.array`, I can't find any way to exclude seemingly unnecessary parts of the `numpy` package such as `numpy.linalg` in the distribution that is created by `py2exe`. This results in the distribution being over 80MB in size, (30MB after being zipped). There is a file in the folder called `numpy.linalg._umath_linalg.pyd` which is 34MB and another called `numpy.linalg.lapack_lite.pyd` which is 18MB - do these really need to be there?! The `.exe` does not run if they are simply deleted.

My question is, **how can I reduce the resulting distribution size?** I am aware there are alternatives to `py2exe` and that if I could remove dependency on `numpy` I wouldn't have this problem, but I would like to stick with both of these.

The following setup script is what I am using, resulting in an 87MB distribution.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys
import shutil

sys.argv.append('py2exe') # No need to type in command line.

py2exe_options = {
        # 'excludes': ['numpy.linalg'], # Stopped the resulting exe from running
        'compressed': True, # Saves 5MB, is this at the cost of some speed?
        'optimize': 1 # I don't really understand what this does.
        }

setup(
    windows=[{'script': 'main.pyw'}],
    options={'py2exe': py2exe_options},
    )

shutil.rmtree('build', ignore_errors=True) # Remove the build folder
```

Comment: Related: http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=57929

Comment: Huh weird. Those two `.pyd` files on my system are only 68 and 26 KB. How did you install Numpy?

Comment: The size depends whether the files include stuff like Intel MKL/OpenBLAS/Atlas statically linked in. If you don't need fast linear algebra, you can minimize size by compiling Numpy without MKL/OpenBLAS/Atlas.

Comment: @pv. How would you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone has any further suggestions I'd like to here them! But here is what I've done so far.

I have managed to reduce the size of the distribution from 87MB to 34MB by reinstalling `numpy` using an 'unoptimized' binary downloaded from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). I believe this is likely to run much slower when doing linear algebra operations, however it works fine for me working with arrays.

**UPDATE**
I have now got my distribution down to 28MB by altering the py2exe options in my `setup.py` script.

```
import distutils.core import setup

py2exe_options = {
        'compressed': True,
        'optimize': 1, # 2 does not work.
        'excludes': ['pydoc', 'doctest', 'pdb', 'inspect', 'pyreadline',
            'locale', 'optparse', 'pickle', 'calendar']
        }

setup(windows=['main.py'], options={'py2exe':py2exe_options})
```